# What does the --audit flag to GNU ld do?

Tags: linux, shared-libraries, ld, glibc, elf

I have an application where I'd like to use the [`rtld-audit`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/rtld-audit.7.html) interface provided by Linux to hook the shared-library loading process. This works great if I use the `LD_AUDIT` environment variable to tell the dynamic linker to use my audit library `audit.so` when I run my program.

However, I'd like to make this a bit more automatic, not requiring special environment setup. GNU `ld` provides an `--audit` flag, described as follows:

> ```
> --audit AUDITLIB
> ```
>
> Adds AUDITLIB to the "DT_AUDIT" entry of the dynamic section. AUDITLIB is not checked for existence, nor will it use the DT_SONAME specified in the library. If specified multiple times "DT_AUDIT" will contain a colon separated list of audit interfaces to use. If the linker finds an object with an audit entry while searching for shared libraries, it will add a corresponding "DT_DEPAUDIT" entry in the output file. This option is only meaningful on ELF platforms supporting the rtld-audit interface.

This suggests to me that if I link my program using `--audit audit.so`, then it should associate my audit library with the program. I would expect that that the audit library would then be loaded when the program is run.

Sure enough, using `readelf`, I can verify that using this flag causes `audit.so` to be registered as an audit library in the ELF header. However, if I run my program without `LD_AUDIT` set, the audit library is never invoked. It seems like I have to set `LD_AUDIT=audit.so` in order to get the behavior I want.

This begs the question: what does the `--audit` flag actually do? any documentation beyond the man page quote above seems to be pretty scarce. It's not clear to me that the Linux dynamic loader even uses the `DT_AUDIT` field in the ELF header. Is this by design?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> This begs the question: what does the --audit flag actually do?

It sets the `DT_AUDIT` dynamic entry, for whoever is willing to pay attention to it.

The problem is that (as of [current trunk](https://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=blob;f=elf/rtld.c;h=52160dfde6be42eba000c4e8136de0d190617270;hb=HEAD)) GLIBC dynamic loader does *not* pay attention to it (look for `process_dl_audit` routine). It only pays attention to `LD_AUDIT` environment variable, and to `--audit` flag when the loader: `ld.so` is invoked directly.

Until someone contributes code to also pay attention to `DT_AUDIT`, the `--audit` flag to `ld` will remain useless.

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation. I had come to a similar conclusion. I was wondering whether the omission was by design or just due to the fact that it hasn't been implemented yet. Sounds like it is the latter.